# Are there any good hostels in San Francisco?

Tags: budget, hostels, san-francisco

I will be staying in San Francisco for about a week. Coming from New Zealand I've already paid an arm and a leg for airfares so I'm quite interested in backpacker accommodation options in or around San Francisco. I'm not looking for anything flash, just clean, friendly and central or close to public transport. Something similar in standard to the YHA hostels in New Zealand.

Comment: Very broad question. Just take a look at hostelworld.com and filter according to your budget and needs. There's no real answer to this question, so voting for close.

Comment: I would say San Francisco has more hostels than anywhere else in the US, it certainly seemed that way 20 years ago when hostelling was less well known in the States. In any case you don't have to worry.

Answer (score 4):

Look on [www.airbnb.com](http://www.airbnb.com).  We have used this service several times and have never been disappointed.  It isn't a hostel, but you can still get rooms pretty cheap.    It is because of this service that we no longer use hotels.